# Nodejs- Trying to retrieve API request details using nodejs script

Tags: node.js

I am trying to fetch nodejs API request details like request header, response details, response time etc using nodejs script

```
request
  .post('http://localhost:3000/api/pet')
  .send({ name: 'Manny', species: 'cat' })
  .set('X-API-Key', 'foobar')
  .set('Accept', 'application/json')
  .end(function(err, res){
    // Calling the end function will send the request 
  });
```

I have tried with the packages like node-monitor- https://github.com/shunanya/Node.js-monitoring but it returns request details of all requests and need to pass server details and options

I was trying to use native node js functions and modules to get request and response details of API request for any request made using express, hapi, request, http

Basically I am trying to trigger one notification script when any http API request occurs from node application

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you wanted?

Comment: I am using express , hapi , request for API requests , out of which I want to monitor /fetch specific API request...I am tried using native node functions like process just to get that specific request details

Comment: The one which you are using above request is used to do request from server to another server not to get any data.

Comment: sorry @PavanVora, I took wrong example and updated the script

Comment: Here where you are trying to fetch? Here you can not get request header. I think you are going in wrong direction. First you should take a look at some basic node server.

Comment: the example, I have mentioned can be any request with or without header , trying capture any request details from application, GET/POST/DELETE/PUT with any native functions like events, process, agent but no luck

Comment: I am using http server for testing in local

Comment: If you node server listen on any port. Then you can do testing using Postman. Awesome tool for testing.

Comment: no @PavanVora, my question is not for testing api requests but to get kind of stats for each request like duration , response , and more insight about request

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159545/discussion-between-divya-reddy-and-pavan-vora).

Comment: I'm going for exam. Can we do it in evening.

Comment: Did you solve the Problem? I'm currently trying to do the same thing